# How do I insert String variable dynamically into a longer String variable?

Tags: java, android, string, formatting

I am trying to take a person's name from a text input field, send it to another Activity, and display that person's name in a sentence within a TextView.

My code is as follows:

This is in one of my Activities.

```
String meaningText = mCurrentColor.getMeaning();
meaningText = String.format(meaningText, mYourName);
mColorText.setText(meaningText);
```

I'm pulling the Meaning string from another class that would contain something along the lines of:

```
"Hey %1$s, you chose this which means blah blah....."
```

Then I want to insert that mYourName variable which is pulled from an EditText in a previous Activity and put that in the above string.

I found that formatting from a Team Treehouse tutorial and it worked in that project's code as I followed along.

I'm using the String.format which takes in a Locale.

I am not sure exactly what is wrong as I mirrored the code to a "T" and just changed some variable names.

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as the String class' length() method returns an int value, the maximum length that would be returned by the method would be Integer.MAX_VALUE, which is 2^31 - 1 (or approximately 2 billion.)

So you can have a String of 2,147,483,647 characters, theoretically. I don't think you should need much more than that.

However, Android system limits your heap space, going as low as 16 MB. Therefore, you'll never practically be able to reach the theoretical limit, and will max out with a String somewhere in the 4-64 million character range.
so, why are you thinking of a longer string variable, when you can directly use your name variable along with a string variable of long length.

```
for Ex:-
String meaning_text = "the very long message you wanted to show..."+ mYourName + "again a long message if you want to show";
```

so my suggestion is to use your name variable directly with message you wanted to show.

Comment: String str = meaningText +""+mYourName

Answer (score 0):

```
EditText edt=(EditText)findViewbyId(R.id.edt);
edt.setText("Dipali");
```

now,getting value from edittext and Replace in TextView String resource.

```
String strEdtTextValue=edt.getText().toString();

TextView tV=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtView)
```

Set text in textview  as xml Resource like as

dummy="Hey %1$s, you chose this which means blah blah....."

add string in resource file

```
<string name="dummy">Hey %1$s, you chose this which means blah blah.....</string>

Resources res = getResources();
String dumyText= (res.getString(R.string.dummy),strEdtTextValue);
tv.setText(dumyText);
```

Its helpful to you.